# Can't post certain images to Reddit

Tags: reddit

On Reddit certain memes I make can't be posted. When I try to post them it loads for about 30 seconds and then brings me to my posts on my profile page. It works for some images but not others. These images aren't NSFW, idk why they aren't working.

Can I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen for all subreddits or just certain ones? Is there any sort of commonality between the images you're trying to post that fail?

Comment: @Eabryt it happens regardless of subreddit, the commonality...well most if not all of them are memes that contain images from a film, but there are millions of memes containing images from films on Reddit and sometimes there are images I try to use that appear on other memes on Reddit.

Comment: Are you trying to upload directly to reddit or an external image hosting site?

Comment: @Eabryt directly to Reddit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a workaround. I can upload the images to Imgur and then post the link to Reddit, and it works just fine. It's inconvenient but functional.